# Confining background color to Triangular tab on QTabBar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabbar

I set up a QTabWidget using the Qt Designer and selected "Triangular" tabs instead of the "Rounded" tabs for the tabShape. I wanted the non selected tabs to be green.  An answer from one of my prior questions  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar
provided me the solution.
However, the background colors were outside the triangular tab's shape, like this:

[image]

Looking on the internet, I found this, which is what I desire:

[image]

How would I modify the following code to keep the color within the border of the triangular tab?

```
self.ui.tabWidget.setStyleSheet(self.ui.tabWidget.styleSheet()
                                            + 'QTabBar::tab:!selected:hover {'
                                              ' border: 2px solid #1e90ff;'
                                              ' background-color: green; }' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(440, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.qtabwidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.qtabwidget.setObjectName("qtabwidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.qtabwidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.qtabwidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Change the shape of the tabs of a QTabWidget"))
        self.qtabwidget.setTabText(self.qtabwidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.qtabwidget.setTabText(self.qtabwidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "Tab 3")

        # changes the shape of the tabs of the QTabWidget
        tab_shape = QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular
        self.qtabwidget.setTabShape(tab_shape)


StyleSheet = '''
QTabWidget {
    background-color: green;
}
QTabWidget::pane {
    border: 1px solid #31363B;
    padding: 2px;
    margin:  0px;
}
QTabBar {
    border: 0px solid #31363B;
    color: yellow;
}
QTabBar::tab:top:selected {
    color: red;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this method is *not* cross-platform nor cross-style. For example, using it on MacOS or with Oxygen style (if set as default for the system or before applying the stylesheet app-wise), the style completely ignores both the shape *and* the background colors.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying, but I don't see the reason for using the object-derived class for the ui in your example. If you did that because the OP used the `self.ui` object, you should have used it in such a fashion (thus, not using the multiple inheritance method), otherwise the code just makes it confusing, also implying that it's ok to edit the pyuic generated output to write programs (and we all know that's a *bad* habit we have to discourage almost on a daily basis). I'd ask you to edit your answer in consideration of this, and also include the issue I reported in the comment above.